# Visual Studio C# Add-In with WPF Prism MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, mvvm, prism

I'm trying to create an Visual Studio Add-In for the UI I decide to implement the Model View ViewModel pattern using the Prism library. It works fine as long you start the project standalone. After I insert it in an Add-In project I am getting that Exception:
"The File or Assembly "Prism.Wpf, PublicKeyToken=91a96d2a154366d8" or one of its dependencies not found. The system can not find the file"

All references are updated and everything is in one single project.

[image]

In Connect.cs I simply want the main Window to come up.

```
public void Exec(string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled)
    {
        handled = false;
        if(executeOption == vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault)
        {
            if(commandName == "SynopticGeneratorAddIn.Connect.SynopticGeneratorAddIn")
            {
                handled = true;
                ShowMainWindow();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ShowMainWindow()
    {
        AutomaticSynopticGenerationCore.Views.MainWindow mainWindow = new AutomaticSynopticGenerationCore.Views.MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
```

Comment: 1) turn on fusion logging 2) where is the binder looking for the prism assembly 3) why isn't it there, or why isn't the binder looking where it is

Comment: Thanks to the Fuslogvw and @Will I can identify the problem. Because when debugging Add-Ins, Visual Studio runs a new instance of Itself and dose not start from bin\Debug Directory like usual. It tries to bind the assemblys from the ../Common7/IDE directory. This happens to all my assemblys. The Prism assembly simply throws an exception first because its the first loaded for the GUI. So how can I force the Add-In to load the assamblys from my directory?

Comment: That's a good question.  I don't know how this works for addins, but there should be some kind of appropriate solution.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one have given an answer, I tell you how i did that. I rewrote it as a VSPackage because add-Ins are considered as obsolete. It did not help. Also updating all Packages did nothing.
The one thing that worked was to use Prism before an instance of a Window gets created. It's an ugly workaround, so if you have something better please tell me.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This function is the callback used to execute a command when the a menu item is clicked.
    /// See the Initialize method to see how the menu item is associated to this function using
    /// the OleMenuCommandService service and the MenuCommand class.
    /// </summary>
    private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        LoadPrism();
        AutomaticSynopticGenerationCore.Views.MainWindow mainWindow = new AutomaticSynopticGenerationCore.Views.MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads Prism from own attached Assembly before window instance gets created
    /// </summary>
    static void LoadPrism()
    {            
        typeof(Prism.Bootstrapper).ToString();
    }
```